# What's the cause of screen glitching?

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, bios

I purchased Gigabyte Aero 16 (2022) with:

- i7-12700h
- OLED 3840x2400 px
- GeForce RTX 3070 Ti
- I also upgraded ram to DDR5-4800 Kingston Fury 64 gb

It was working fine out of the box for the first 2 days except for a minor screen glitch on screen wakeup (see video):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ljwX.jpg

I suspected that it was caused by one of these:

1. Gigabyte Control Center (GCC) (which feels very buggy) or other pre-installed software
2. Outdated Gigabyte BIOS
3. Outdated Intel/Nvidia/other drivers

What I did:

1. I uninstalled GCC
2. I updated BIOS to the newest "BIOS FB0A & EC F008"
3. I updated Intel Xe to the newest 31.0.101.4032 drivers
4. I updated Nvidia to the newest 31.0.15.2824 Studio (stable) drivers

And it became much worse because now it's glitching way more (it sometimes reaches stability but frequent small and large glitches return often):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M7uB.jpg

Even worse: either entire computer or screen hanged twice in the past 2 hours and I had to do a hard reboot.

What should I do?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you need to take it back to wherever you bought it from and get a replacement.

Comment: When it glitches and is dark, hold a flashlight and see if its a backlight - and I'd second checking if its replacable/fixable under warranty

Comment: Update: I just reinstalled Windows 11 from ISO and all glitching/flickering is completely gone. But Intel and Nvidia drivers are not updated yet, so we'll see shortly if glitching will return.

Comment: Update 2: It did happen again on new Windows 11. But replacing RAM seems to have fixed this for real. So, RAM was the problem with 99% probability. All glitches are gone with the default RAM. Thank you for answering, that was helpful to get additional opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues. Based on many hours of collecting information and going through the process, here is the solution I used that actually works:

1. Open task manager. End all NVIDIA tasks.
2. Uninstall (add or remove programs) all NVIDIA software
3. Uninstall (add or remove programs) anything related to Gigabyte
4. Go to NVIDIA's website and install Geforce Experience. This will include game ready driver and and NVIDIA settings panel. Keep the game-ready driver; the studio driver is a dumbed-down (stable) version of this.
5. Go to https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/AERO-16--Intel-12th-Gen/support#support-childModelsMenu and select your laptop. Go to Downloads and download the latest drivers (except NVIDIA), firmware and GCC.
6. This will take a while and require several restarts. Once everything is working well, I recommend you clone your system drive so you know you have a good copy of everything when the next Gigabyte update comes along and screws something else up.

EXTRA NUGGET: No matter what you do, DO NOT download the Bluetooth driver from Windows Update in the Optional Updates section. You need to use the Bluetooth driver that Gigabyte makes available on its own website.

Comment: Thanks! In my case replacing RAM solved all problems. I'm using Intel 31.0.101.4091 drivers, Nvidia 31.0.15.2824 Studio, BIOS FB0A & EC F008 and I don't have any problems. Not a single glitch in the past 10 days. But this laptop has some remaining problems: (1) BIOS looks ancient compared to modern computers, (2) Wi-Fi is definitely broken somehow (replacing Wi-Fi card doesn't help) because I get 100 kB/s download speeds and many disconnects (but bluetooth works, albeit with limited range to ~4 meters) and GCC 23.01.09.01 ignores "limit battery to 90% charge" still, so it's a crap software.